# Call google maps api event addListener using dart:js

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dart, dart-js-interop

In the Google Maps API v3 they have stated that we need to do this to open the infowindow when the marker gets clicked:

```dart
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Now I am trying to duplicate this in dart using the js library. So far I have something like this:

```dart
final google_maps = context['google']['maps'];

var myLatlng = [43.5, -6.5];
var center = new JsObject(google_maps['LatLng'], myLatlng);

var mapTypeId = google_maps['MapTypeId']['ROADMAP'];

var mapOptions = new JsObject.jsify({
  "center": center,
  "zoom": 8,
  "mapTypeId": mapTypeId
});

var map = new JsObject(google_maps['Map'], [querySelector('#map-canvas'), mapOptions]);

var marker = new JsObject(google_maps['Marker'], [new JsObject.jsify({
  'position': center,
  'map': map,
  'title': 'Hello World!'
})]);

var tooltip = '<div id="content">Info window coontent</div>';

var infowindow = new JsObject(google_maps['InfoWindow'], [new JsObject.jsify({
"content": tooltip
})]);


google_maps['event'].callMethod('addListener', [marker, 'click', () {
  infowindow.callMethod('open',[map,marker]);
}]);
```

The issue is that I set the 'addListener' method through google_maps['event'], but when I click the marker, I get a NoSuchMethodError:

```dart
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
Receiver: Closure: () => dynamic
Tried calling: call(Instance of 'JsObject')
Found: call()
```

I am aware that there is a [google_maps dart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps), but I want the interact with the javascript api using dart's js library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `google_maps` package ? It use `dart:js` under the cover and provide a typed API much simpler to use than directly using `dart:js`.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin, not that I don't want to use it, the opposite. It's that I was starting to look into dart and google maps and when I couldn't make this bit work I precisely "found" that package. I'm using it actually but I wanted to know what I was doing wrong and that's why I asked this and the comment was for avoiding answers telling me about the package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your closure has zero arguments.

```
() {
   infowindow.callMethod('open',[map,marker]);
}
```

You just have to give it an argument as stated in the error message:

```
(event) {
   infowindow.callMethod('open',[map,marker]);
}
```